# Level 2: What do the different order types on LSE represent?

Tags: united-kingdom, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, level-2-quotes, london-stock-exchange

Here are a list of successful trades from a Level 2 order book. The column to the left of the time the trade went through is the "trade type". It is usually one of three things:

1. `AT`
2. `O`
3. *Blank*

Is anyone able to give a description of each? As I understand it, `AT` stands for *Automatic* and `O` stands for *Ordinary*, but I've not been able to find a description of what consitutes an "automatic" or "ordinary" trade? And if `O` is Ordinary, then what does no identifier represent?

[image: Level 2 trades]

Comment: Are you using ADVFN? If so, you should probably contact their customer support, since they did not document a blank trade type in https://uk.advfn.com/Help/trade-types-1549.html

Comment: Is this the list of trades for Vodafone Group Plc (VOD) on 2021-12-22? If not, what is the name of the stock? With this information, someone with access to different source of last trade information may be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An automatic trade (`AT`) is a normal on-exchange trade, created during regular trading by the matching engine from order(s) in the order book.

An ordinary (`O`) trade is a normal *off*-exchange trade, agreed between the counterparties elsewhere and then reported to the exchange.

I don't think a blank type has a standard meaning; you may need to check with your data supplier.

There are many other trade types, some specific to market segments, trading session types, publication timing, &c. For example, the next most common one is probably uncrossing trade (`UT`), which uncrosses the order book at the end of an auction period. (The LSE lists some more [here](https://www.londonstockexchange.com/help/whats-issuer-profile-overview#what-is-trades-table-).)